# Not able to launch msn using url schema

Tags: ios4, url-scheme

I want to launch MSN through my iphone App.
I am using url shema-

```
BOOL msn = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"msnim://"]];
if (msn) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"msnim://"]];
}
else {

    UIAlertView * errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"MSN not Installed" message: nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]; 
    [errorAlert show];  
    [errorAlert release];
```

but its not working. 
Am i using wrong custom url for MSN????
If yes,then what is the url scheme for MSN.